# cant run asp.net website after I moved it from the server to local machine - cannot find table 0

Tags: .net, database, enterprise-library

so i have this old app from 2005 built on .Net 3.5. The app is running just fine on a W2k3 server with sql server 2005.

I have copied the app files and the imported the database from a backup on my localhost xp machine with sql server 2008. I have set the database compatibility to 90 which is 100% sql server 2005 compat mode. Put the files in an Visual Studio website project and ran it with "Browse". I get an error of "Cannot find table 0".

I have enabled debug in web.config and get to a file where the problem resides. If i count the result then the error moves to another file with similar code. I know that i should count the result but the app runs just fine as it is on the webserver.

The application is using Enterprise Library 1.1 and the db connection info is in a dataConfiguration.config referenced in web.config. I have edited dataConfiguration.config to reflect my connection information on localhost.

The code triggering the error is like:

```
        DataSet dsflash = new DataSet();
        dsflash = objFlash.GetLatestBanner();
        if (dsflash.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)  //error here
        {
//            lnkLink.HRef = dsflash.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Link"].ToString();
```

At this moment i am beat and have no idea where to turn ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if you function `GetLatestBanner()` is returning a dataset with some tables in it. You can also have a condition to check tables count in dataset as -

```
if( dsflash.Tables.Count > 0 ) 
{
   if (dsflash.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)  //error here
   {
      //your rest of the code.
   }
}
```

This will ensure that only if there are tables present in your dataset, it will move ahead with your code.

Comment: as I said << If i count the result then the error moves to another file with similar code. I know that i should count the result but the app runs just fine as it is on the webserver. >>

Comment: @Andrei - Then the problem is in your GetLatestBanner() method, which you need to debug on why it is not returning you the proper dataset which your code is expecting.